# How do I pass reference to Navigator into renderScene?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been experimenting with React Native and I'm having trouble passing a reference to navigator into the scene I'm rendering. Without navigator, NewsList items can't trigger a scene change.

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <Navigator
            initialRoute={ { name: 'NewsList', index: 0 } }
            renderScene={ ( route, navigator ) => NewsList }
        />                                                      
    );                                                          
},
```

Similarly, in the render scene function I need to pass navigator to the row rendering function.

```
<UIExplorerPage noSpacer={true} noScroll={true}>
    <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this._renderRow}
        onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
    />
</UIExplorerPage>
```

What is the idiomatic way to pass references like this around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're saying that your news list item components need a reference to navigator in order to trigger a navigation event. This (IMO) is the wrong approach.

Instead, pass the list items a callback. The callback is a method on the parent news list component, and that already has a reference to navigator that you can call. In this way you can avoid passing the navigator all the way down your component hierarchy.

I can give a code example if this isn't clear :)

Answer (score 9):

Like Colin mentioned, you need to pass a callback to your list items. Given below is code from the an example project (UIExplorer) in react native itself.

Here, we're passing the `navigator` object to the NavMenu which is the list component.

```js
var TabBarExample = React.createClass({
    // Other methods... blah blah
    renderScene: function(route, nav) {
        switch (route.id) {
          case 'navbar':
            return <NavigationBarSample navigator={nav} />;
          case 'breadcrumbs':
            return <BreadcrumbNavSample navigator={nav} />;
          case 'jumping':
            return <JumpingNavSample navigator={nav} />;
          default:
            return (
              <NavMenu
                message={route.message}
                navigator={nav}
                onExampleExit={this.props.onExampleExit}
              />
            );
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
          <Navigator
            style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{ message: "First Scene", }}
            renderScene={this.renderScene}
            configureScene={(route) => {
              if (route.sceneConfig) {
                return route.sceneConfig;
              }
              return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom;
            }}
          />
        );
      }
});
```

In the NavMenu component, we're passing a callback on the `onPress` of every NavButton.

```js
class NavMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.scene}>
        <Text style={styles.messageText}>{this.props.message}</Text>
        <NavButton
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigator.push({
              message: 'Swipe right to dismiss',
              sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight,
            });
          }}
          text="Float in from right"
        />
        <NavButton
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigator.push({
              message: 'Swipe down to dismiss',
              sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom,
            });
          }}
          text="Float in from bottom"
        />
        // Omitted rest of the NavButtons.
      </ScrollView>
     );
}
```

Here's a [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/NavigatorExample.js) to the example.

Comment: literally spent hours on this, this answer is quite clear, thank you for saving me from the navigator hell, the navigator needs a blog post to teach people how to use it

Answer (score 2):

The question was worded kinda vaguely. I resolved my issue by adding navigator to UIExplorerPage, e.g `<UIExplorerPage navigator={navigator} />`. Properties can be accessed within UIExplorerPage using `this.props`.